# Decoding error: “Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.”

Tags: json, swift4

I have problems with JSON decoding. I red other answers for this issue and I did same, but I still get the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: r) { (data, response, error) in
    do {
        guard let data = data else { return }
        let banners = try JSONDecoder().decode([Banner].self, from: data)
        print(banners)
    } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}.resume()

struct Banner: Decodable {
    var title: String
    var desc: String
    var image: String
}
```

JSONResponse:

```
[
     {
    "id": "b4a95512-8de2-4621-8956-3289e991fb0b",
    "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
    },
  {
   "id": "4e1c703d-4841-469b-be2e-8f15d6cbd0c3",
   "title": "Lays",
   "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
  },
  {
   "id": "4315705e-e6fc-4dfa-a52e-c9de2031ed53",
   "desc": "ФРУТОНЯНЯ Для детского питания с яблоком, для малышей от 0 до 3 лет",
   "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
  },
  {
   "id": "0b8e40ae-5e13-4bdd-905d-a13ffdd94b65",
   "title": "Бульмени",
   "desc": "ГОРЯЧАЯ ШТУЧКА Со сливочным маслом",
   "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
  }
]
```

Comment: This JSON and code cannot cause this error. You should get a `keyNotFound` error. And delete `let error as NSError`. Decoding errors are never `NSError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `"id"` key missing in your struct. `desc` and `title` are not provided for all the elements in the json response, so they should be optional.

Use this struct instead:

```
struct Banner: Codable {
    let id: String
    let image: String
    let title, desc: String?
}
```

Also, catch the error this way:

```
catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: The `id` property is not required in the struct if you have no need for that data.